# CPUID in x86 Architecture

Tags: c++, assembly, x86, cpuid

I am trying to access the Information using CPUID in C++.
I have produced this code so far and could not go any longer.
I found some useful articles here and on the web but they did not seem to help me.

I am supposed to use instructions and registers from x88 only.
This is the code.

```
int b[5] = {0} ;

for (int a = 0; a < 5 ; a++)
{
    __cpuid (b,a) ;
    std::cout << "The code " << a << " gives " << b[0] << std::endl;
}
```

I am unable to go any further as I cannot understand how to fetch the information from this array bitwise. I have this [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPUID) and [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hskdteyh%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) article which explains the scheme.
My question is not very good but I would appreciate any help or direction in this regard.

Comment: I mean iAPx8088. I am sorry if I say it wrong as I am learning it.

Comment: The 8088 didn't have a CPUID. Being  the first generation, it really didn't need one...

Comment: the 8088/8086 did not have a cpuid, it wasnt until much later.  I have not looked at the cpuid code in a long while, but they used self modifying code to determine the prefetch buffer depth and that is how you distinguished between the very early x86 processors (8088 is part of that x86 family it was an 8086 with an 8 bit external bus).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose your problem is not about accessing the array data through an index, which is as you already done `b[0]`, `b[1]` and so on. You need a little bit of bit (!) manipulation. You have to mask out the bits you are not interested in and interpret what is left; e.g.

```
    (b[0] & 0xF0) >> 4
```

will give you 4 bits (4-7) that are the model according to MSDN. And so on. Consider the following

```
    3            2            1
    1098 7654 3210 9876 5432 1098 7654 3210
    0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 
    \R_/ \ext_Fam/ \eM/ RRpp \fm/ \md/ \sd/

    R = reserved
    ext_Fam = extended family
    eM = extended model
    pp = processor type
    fm = family
    md = model
    sd = stepping id
```

(int supposed 32 bit int — or wider)

If you want e.g. the processor type, you need:

```
    0000 0000 0000 0000 0011 0000 0000 0000 
    \R_/ \ext_Fam/ \eM/ RRpp \fm/ \md/ \sd/
```

and then shift (logical shift) right of 3 "nibbles" (12). So

```
   (b[0] >> 12) & 3
```

will give you a number representing processor type. (The number 3 is 11 in base 2, so it's the right mask to select only the rightmost two bits).

Comment: I get many things from that.
I am still unclear about the parameters we send to the function, what happens when we change them at function call, as b[0] and b[1], etx

Comment: with "the function" you mean `__cpuid`? It fills the array b with some data, according to the input parameter `a`. What I've shown in the answer is the case when a == 1. The b[0] holds what I've written, b[1] other data and so on. You have to interpret the code according to the value of a (it is not the index into b, of course!). Just a different set of informations/data at each iteration. You output just the "first" `int`.